# Comparing strings using relational operators C++

Tags: c++, string, relational

How come when comparing strings...

```
string e = "11" 
string f = "102" 
string s = "8" 


e > s - this statement is false 
f > s - and this is also false
```

How come those statements are false? And what are the rules when comparing two strings to each other?

Comment: Those are string literals, and the comparison will end up being between `const char*` which is simply comparing pointer addresses, which is useless for what you're probably looking for (lexicographical sorting or maybe numerical sorting?)

Comment: std::string values are compared character by character. Imagine replacing characters '0'...'9' with characters 'a'...'j'. "bb" < "i" alphabetically, and same with "bac" < "j".

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Details do matter, `"11" > "8"` is different from `string("11") > string("8")`

Comment: taking into account the edit, the duplicate isnt a duplicate anymore. reopened the question

Answer (score 2):

Using relational operators on strings in C/C++ will simply compare the memory addresses of the strings. Obviously `"11"` and `"8"` are occupying 2 different areas of memory, so it could be false, unless the address where `"11"` is stored happens to be stored in an address greater than `"8"`, but it's random.

Keep in mind that you can use `string::compare`, however, it's comparing the ASCII code's of the strings. Since `"1"` (ASCII Code 49) is less than `"8"` (ASCII Code 56), it will still be false. You need to use `stoi` to convert the string to an integer, then compare the integers.

Comment: Good answer, but it may be worth mentioning/explaining that even if he **were** comparing `std::string`'s so that it would compare the string values and not the addresses, "11" would still evaluate to less than "8".

Comment: No need engage in such blatant ASCIIism here. <g> `'1'` is required to be less than `'8'` in **every** character set supported by C or C++ compilers.